# Is there any issue in Windows 7-10 with starting a folder name or file name with a period (aka dot)?

Tags: windows, backup, ftp, android, files-folders

I am backing up an Android device via FTP onto a Windows NTFS volume.  As part of the backup, I want to backup the hidden files and folders from the Android device, which uses the convention to begin hidden files and folders with a period (aka dot).

My FTP software has no problem with this.  Also, I don't use Microsoft's Windows Explorer / File Explorer, so I'm not concerned about its limitations.

What I am concerned about is the possibility of causing any problems by having filenames and folder names that begin with a period.  Are there any such issues with Windows 7-10?  If so, what's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: From here:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file    Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".   So my answer was not correct and I have deleted it.

Comment: No problem John, and thank you for the update!  The allowance of a period at the beginning of a name is true for both files *and* folders, correct?

Comment: You can use a period for the beginning of a file or folder according to the Microsoft document about this issue.

Comment: @John Thanks John!

Comment: This is a fairly important concept so I reworked my answer into a more solid and correct answer

Comment: @John Looks great. Upvoted. Thanks John!

Answer (score 3):

There is a document from Microsoft dated in 2020 that sheds good light on this issue.

[Microsoft File, Folder naming conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

With respect in particular to using periods at the beginning of Files and Folders:

> 1] (you can) Use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the
> current directory, for example ".\temp.txt". For more information, see
> Paths.
>
> 2] (you can) Use two consecutive periods (..) as a directory component in a
> path to represent the parent of the current directory, for example
> "..\temp.txt". For more information, see Paths.
>
> 3] However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first
> character of a name. For example, ".temp"

So you are able to use periods at the beginning of file and folders as you asked in your question. It should not cause any issue.

There may be some apps that do not understand the usage but that should not cause an issue.

Comment: I disagree. The only problems with such files is that Windows Explorer can not create such files. Besides this limitation no problems arise from such files or folders. I have dozens of such files created by Android Studio, Android SDK and other software that has not been adapted to Windows. Therefore I can say that this answer is just wrong.

Comment: @Robert - I reworked my answer to correct it and to include the main reference from Microsoft on this issue.

Comment: Microsoft worked the last years hard to remove all the remaining obstacles from Windows 10 that have to to with "unusual" file and directory names. I assume this was done mostly because of WSL/WSL2 which makes Linux files common on NTFS file-systems. Since a few versions (1909?) even the Windows Explorer is capable of creating files7folders staring with a dot. Before that was only possible using comand-line.